# UIImage has no member fontAwesomeIconWithName

Tags: ios, swift, font-awesome

I have the following Swift3 code

```
let leftImage = UIImage.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Bars, textColor: UIColor.white, size: CGSizeMake(width: 30, height: 30))
```

Am using Swift3 in Xcode_8_3_2 with the following in my Podfile

```
pod 'FontAwesome.swift'
```

Gettting the error :

> UIImage has no member fontAwesomeIconWithName

What's the reason for this error? How to fix it?

Comment: Did you include the FontAwesome library in your Swift file?

Comment: what @TheValyreanGroup said, plus I don't see `fontAwesomeIconWithName` in the library; are you sure you shouldn't be using `fontAwesomeIcon(name: FontAwesome, textColor: UIColor, size: CGSize, backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear) -> UIImage`?

Comment: Just to double check, did you run `pod install` after adding to the podfile, re-opened the project with the workspace file etc? Have you tried adding a target to the podfile? Does FontAwesome.swift need to be imported?

Comment: Thanks @lukkea It seems they updated the API but not the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this using [lukkea's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882630/lukkea) suggestion as follows:

```
let leftImage = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .bars, textColor: UIColor.white, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
```